# Como alocar uma pilha dinâmica, com tamanho fornecido pelo usuário?

Tags: c, gerenciamento-de-memória, stack, malloc

Quero alocar uma pilha dinâmica com o tamanho fornecido pelo usuário, depois tratar ela como um "vetor" seria mais ou menos o que fiz na função `ALOCA`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
struct figuras
{
    char nome[100];
    char idade[5];
    char selecao[100];
};
typedef struct elemento* Pilha;

struct elemento
{
    struct figuras dados;
    struct elemento *prox;
};
typedef struct elemento Elem;
//FUNCOES
Pilha* cria_Pilha();


void menu()
{
    printf("1 - Criar Pilha Dinamicamente\n2 - Inserir Elementos\n3 - Remover Elementos\n4 - Imprimir Elementos\n5 - Checar Pilha vazia\n6 - Checar Pilha Cheia\n7 - Destruir Pilha\n");
    printf("Digite uma opcao\n");
}

int main()
{
    int *ptam;
    int tampilha, op;
    do{
    menu();
    scanf("%d", &op);
    if(op == 1)//CRIAR
    {
        system("cls");
        printf("Digite o Tamanho da sua Pilha\n");
        scanf("%d", &tampilha);
        //ptam = &tampilha;
        Pilha *pi = cria_Pilha();
        ALOCA(pi, tampilha);
    }else
        if(op == 2)//PUSh (INSERIR)
        {

        }else
            if(op == 3)//POP(remover1)
            {

            }else
                if(op == 4)//IMRPIMIR
                {

                }else
                    if(op == 5)//Checar pilha vazia
                    {

                    }else
                        if(op == 6)//CHECAR PILHA CHEIA
                        {

                        }else{//DESTRUIR PILHA
                        }



 }while(op != 8);

    return 0;
}



//funcoes escopo
Pilha* cria_Pilha()
{
    Pilha* pi = (Pilha*) malloc(sizeof(Pilha));
    if(pi != NULL){
        *pi = NULL;
    }

    return pi;
}
int ALOCA(Pilha* pi, int tam)
{
    if(pi == NULL)
        return 0;
    Elem* no;
    no = (Elem*) malloc(tam * sizeof(Elem));
    if(no == NULL)
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 2):

Não é assim. Se é uma pilha então seria algo assim:

```
Pilha pi = malloc(sizeof(Elem) * tam);
```

Não precisa mais nada a não ser decidir o que fazer se der erro de alocação (o que está errado na função apresentada na pergunta. Você aloca espaço para toda a pilha, ou seja, tem espaço para cada um dos elementos que pode colocar nela.

Se quiser uma lista ligada, e parte do código indica isso, só precisa fazer:

```
Elem *no = malloc(sizeof(Elem));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Allocation/List.c).

Também precisaria tratar o erro, o que está errado na pergunta.

Nesse caso não existirá uma estrutura que suportará a lista, cada nó da lista é parte dela.

O código mistura conceitos, precisa decidir se quer uma pilha ou lista ligada.

O código tem vários outros erros, e ele pode ser escrito de forma bem melhor.